# How to make query with Group By and Count in MySql?

Tags: mysql

I have this tables:

L table // teachers

| KL | org |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | test |
| 2 | test1 |

G table // groups

| KG | fac |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | maths |
| 2 | physics |

R table

| KR | KL | KG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |

And I want to make this query: How many orgs have teachers who give lectures at more than one faculty?

So here is my query, but it is not working as intended:

```
SELECT COUNT(L.org)
FROM (L INNER JOIN R ON L.KL = R.KL)
    INNER JOIN G ON G.KG = R.KG
GROUP BY G.fac, L.org
HAVING COUNT(G.fac) > 1;
```

Expected output: 1 (beacause only teacher with Id 1 have more than one faculty, so count of orgs is 1)

Can you help me to figure out what is wrong?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the expected output ?

Comment: Edited, add the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the IDs of all teachers who have lectured to more than one faculty using `GROUP BY` AND `HAVING` clauses, then use `COUNT()` function to count  the records in this dataset :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (
  SELECT L.KL
  FROM L
  INNER JOIN R ON L.KL = R.KL
  INNER JOIN G ON G.KG = R.KG
  GROUP BY L.KL
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS S
```